# Is there a way to determine how much money you have above $10,000,000?

Tags: ps3, borderlands

After your bank exceeds $10,000,000 the cash display in your inventory just stays maxed out at $9,999,999.  Many high-level items even have their prices displayed as $9,999,999.  Is there any practical way to determine the *actual* amount these displays represent?

Note:  I'm asking as a player on a PS3 - cheats or other methods specific to the PC are of no use to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Players wishing to know exactly how much money their characters have (and who don't mind losing 7% of it) can calculate this from the death of their characters. The 7% that the character lost will be displayed on the left of the screen along with the New-U message. The character's money before the reconstruction can be calculated as follows: money = fee / 7 * 100.

Borderlands Wikia entry on [Money](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Money)

Comment: Note the 7% loss isn't as bad as it sounds, if you play long enough you'll eventually get to an Overflow in your money counter which will reset your money to $0

Comment: This is a way (It's arguable whether or not it's a *good* way) to figure out how much you have on-hand - but how do you figure out the actual price of items listed at $9,999,999?

Answer (score 0):

### Only Suitable for PC

If you have a mod program installed, such as *Willow Tree* this program reads your saved games and displays the correct full amount of money along with a pile of other information and tweaks you can perform on your character and inventory.

**Please remember this is somewhat a mod, and all mods are not guaranteed to work and may corrupt your game save, so back up!**

EDIT: question re-tagged, this answer is only viable for PC versions of Borderlands.